# command working in cmd but not through php shell_exec

Tags: php, cmd, pdf-generation, shell-exec, docto

I have a command in cmd which looks like below

```
C:\wamp\www\editor\DocTo-master\exe\docto -f C:\wamp\www\editor\uploaded\uploaded_files_21_original\AffidavitinDIR-4.docx -O "C:\wamp\www\editor\uploaded\uploaded_files_21_original\pdf\21.pdf" -T wdFormatPDF
```

When I run this in cmd, it works absolutely fine and gives output(doc to pdf) as expected.
However when I put the same command in php shell_exec like

```
shell_exec('C:\wamp\www\editor\DocTo-master\exe\docto -f C:\wamp\www\editor\uploaded\uploaded_files_21_original\AffidavitinDIR-4.docx -O "C:\wamp\www\editor\uploaded\uploaded_files_21_original\pdf\21.pdf" -T wdFormatPDF');
```

I dont get the desired output with the above code in php.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You have to escape ` \ ` to ` \\ `

Comment: I tried to replace them, but still its not working!

Comment: I see you're running wamp, did you ever find a solution to that problem? I have the same issue with an xampp installation on Windows Server 2016...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like most of the problems have to do with permissions or redirection.

Your current user credentials allow you to create files in that directory but does the webserver username?

Redirect stderr to stdout to get error information.

Is the quoting right?

Look in the webserver error logs.

Comment: This is what I get in the error log file

FileToConvert:C:\wamp\www\editor\uploaded\uploaded_files_21_original\AffidavitinDIR-4.docx
OutputFile:C:\wamp\www\editor\uploaded\uploaded_files_21_original\pdf\21.pdf
Ext17
*****************************************
Error: EOleException  This command is not available because no document is open
*****************************************
Error: Exiting with Error Code : 220

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of [docto](http://github.com/tobya/docto).

This is most probably a permissions issue in that php is not necessarily given the correct permissions to run word on your server.

I am running this myself on a Windows 2012 server running Word 2010, it works fine.  DocTo is installed on a subdirectory above the Webserver root.

PHP is running as NTSystem Authority

Also I am using exec rather than shell_exec not sure if that makes any differnce

Answer (score 0):

For fix this problem you must create Desktop folder in these paths:

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop

Then go to (Control Panel\Administrative Tools\Services) and right click on your apache service. go to "Log On" tab and enable "Allow service to interact with desktop" option.

Then reset your apache service.

http://pmlearning.info